# Coordinator Layout - Toolbar animation, Toolbar doesn't collapse

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using below `Layout` in the `Activity`, but the `Toolbar` wouldn't hide no matter how many changes I do.

The `Toolbar` has to hide as I scroll down the `RecyclerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You mean you don't want toolbar to be show while scroll up ?

Comment: I don't want toolbar to be show while scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line : `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"`,

**Try to add:**

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

In the `Toolbar`. As i remember, `"parallax"` was used to give the `Images`, *parallax* effect on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.